# Does CreateSpace (Print-On-Demand) print and ship books to the customer, or do I need to do that?

Tags: self-publishing, print-on-demand, amazon

If I self-publish a book on Amazon using CreateSpace, when someone orders a copy, do I need to go to a local printing company, have it printed, and shipped to them?

Or does CreateSpace print the book and ship it to the customer?  Is that how print-on-demand works?

Answer (score 4):

I published my book at CreateSpace, too. If an order gets in, they print the book, ship it to the buyer and collect the money.

Simple work.

Answer (score 2):

That is how print-on-demand works. It would be best to order a proof, before you publish, which is around 10 dollars U.S, but after you publish with CreateSpace, they will print your book, and ship to whoever buys.